# Probability of drawing 6 specific letters from a set of 144 with 21 draws

Tags: conditional-probability

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I am struggling to find a method to calculate the probability for the situation below:

I have a set of 144 scrabble tiles with the following letter distribution.

2  x , K, Q, X, Z

3  x B, C, F, H, M, P, V, W, Y

4  x G

5  x L

6  x D, S, U

8  x N

9  x T, R

11  x O

12  x I

13  x A

18  x E

I am trying to calculate the probability having the letters "I S N E A T" in any order when 21 tiles are picked from the set of 144.

I would appreciate any help on methods to calculate this

Thanks in advance - Gary

Answer (score 1):

There are a total of ${144\choose 21}=8943919960348862933558400$ ways to choose 21 tiles from the 144 available.

Let $I=\{12,6,8,18,13,9\}$ be the counts of tiles corresponding 
to the letters I,S,N,E,A,T. Then the number of *bad* samples, i.e, missing one 
of the required letters, of size 21 can be worked out using the inclusion-exclusion principle,
giving $$\sum_{A\subseteq I, A\neq\emptyset} {144-S(A)\choose 21}(-1)^{|A|+1}
=6947914061108945063687691. $$ Here $S(A)=\sum_{x\in A}x$ gives the number of 
tiles corresponding to the set $A$. For instance, when  $A=\{12,6\}$ 
we have $S(A)=18$, since there are eighteen tiles labelled I or S.

Subtracting gives the number of *good* samples $1996005899239917869870709$.

Dividing by the total number of samples gives 
the chance of getting all six letters I,S,N,E,A,T: 
$${1996005899239917869870709\over 8943919960348862933558400}\approx .22317.$$

Comment: Many Thanks indeed Byron, your assistance is greatly appreciated.